# Sending a callback function from Dart to Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, flutter, dart

I am using a flutter channel in order to communicate with the android (Kotlin) native side of my application. But I don't know if it is possible to send a callback (in this case a function that just accept a string as argument) from Dart to Kotlin ? If yes, how should I type it ?

Let's say for example, I have this dart function

```dart
void _acceptEngineOutput(String output){
}
```

And this Kotlin function

```
fun readEngineOutput(callback) {
   while(process.isAlive) {
       line = outputBuffer.readLine()
       if (line != null && line.length > 0) callback(line)
   }
}
```

**How should callback parameter by typed, so that I can pass in the _acceptOutput function ?**

This is my MainActivity class, for now, I just miss the type of callback in sendEngineOutput method.

```
package com.loloof64.chess_exercise_manager_flutter

import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import com.kalab.chess.enginesupport.ChessEngineResolver
import com.kalab.chess.enginesupport.ChessEngine
import java.io.File

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "loloof64.chess_utils/engine_discovery"


    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler(
                        { call, result ->
                            if (call.method.equals("copyAllEnginesToAppDir")) {
                                copyAllEnginesToAppDir()
                                result.success(1)
                            }
                            else if (call.method.equals("setEngineOutputListener")) {
                                setEngineOutputListener(call.arguments)
                                result.success(output)
                            }
                            else {
                                result.notImplemented();
                            }
                        }
                )
    }

    private fun setEngineOutputListener(callback) {

    }

}
```

Comment: see `setMethodCallHandler()` method on the flutter side

Comment: Thank you. I'll try with it.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel/setMethodCallHandler.html

Comment: In fact I'm already using it in the big snippet I posted above, but is there a way to improve it ?

Comment: no, you use it in kotlin, I said you should use it in dart code

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've read too fast.

Comment: I've managed. Thank you very much. Could you post your advice as an answer ?

Comment: feel free to write a self answer 

Comment: Ok, then I'll do it.

Comment: btw you can also use `EventChannel` and its `receiveBroadcastStream()` method so that you can use `Stream.listen()` for listening for a streamed data from your kotlin code

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I'll also have a look at it.

Comment: your welcome, i forgot to say that you can also use `StreamBuilder` directly with such `Stream` but i think you know it well

Comment: In fact I didn't (I'm not used to Streams nor RxJava). Thank you.

Comment: so maybe its good time to start... what are you doing with the data sent from kotlin? what kind of data it is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206341/discussion-between-loloof64-and-pskink).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @pskink made me notify : I simple have to use `setMethodCallHandler` in my Flutter code.

1. In my MainActivity, where I needed to execute the callback, I call something like `methodChannel?.invokeMethod("processEngineOutput", line)`. Here processEngineOutput is the reference to be caught from my Flutter code
2. In my Flutter code, when building the Wiget, I set up the callback for the platform communication. For example

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    platform.setMethodCallHandler(_processEngineOutput); // <---- HERE !!!! --->

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Chess exercises manager'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ChessBoard(
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

3. I define the callback `_processEngineOutput` as a future and check that the method invocation is the good one

```dart
Future<void> _processEngineOutput(MethodCall call) async {
    if (call.method != 'processEngineOutput') return;
    var line = call.arguments;
    print(line);
  }
```